# How to add condition with for_each in dynmic block

Tags: azure, terraform

Here in the below code, I'm planning to achieve that if value is null ,I don't want to execute a block of the code or else yes

```
dynamic "request_uri_condition" {
    
              for_each      =  delivery_rule.value.request_uri_condition_operator != "" ?1 : 0
              content{
              operator      = delivery_rule.value.request_uri_condition_operator
              match_values  = delivery_rule.value.request_uri_condition_match_values
            }
          }
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "delivery_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    cdnendpoint                            = string
    name                                   = string
    order                                  = number
    request_scheme_conditions_match_values = list(string)
    request_scheme_conditions_operator     = string
}))
}
```

**error:  Cannot use a number value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the syntax below, determine whether `delivery_rules` is empty or not.

> **error: Cannot use a number value in for_each. An iterable collection is required.**

***It means that a conditional operator should be given as a string rather than a number (?1:0). I verified it in my environment after making the changes, and everything worked as expected.***

```bash
dynamic "request_uri_condition" {
    
         for_each  = var.delivery_rule != "" ? var.delivery_rule : "default"   
              content{     
              operator      = delivery_rule.value.request_uri_condition_operator
              match_values  = delivery_rule.value.request_uri_condition_match_values
            }
         }
```

***terraform initialized successfully with*** `terraform init`:

[image]

`terraform plan`***executed with no "type" errors:***

[image]

Refer [terraform conditionals](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals),  [terraform registry Cdn template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_frontdoor_rule)